# Google Analytics relationships between views

Tags: google-analytics

I have a custom variable set up so that when a user sees page `x` it means they are a customer.

This page is after a log-in and can only be accessed once a user has registered.

I have two views set up in GA based on a user having the custom variable or not

- **Non-Customer**
- **Customer**

How would GA manage the view relationship between these two users?

E.g.

1. A new user comes on the site, there is no custom variable picked up
   so it registers as a 'Non-Customer'
2. This user registers and then logs in and sees page X, the variable
   registers as 'Customer'

Would I be able to see this user in both views in GA? Or does the user count within the view transfer from Non-Customer to Customer?

Many thanks for your help.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your implementation; in particular the Scope of your Custom Dimension (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#processing).

If it's a Hit level dimension, then one view will see all the hits with **Non-Customer**, and the other will see those with **Customer**.

If it's a Session level dimension, then whichever value was applied last will be attributed to every hit in the Session.

Comment: Hi, Thank you @j brazier, that makes complete sense. They are applied at a user level . Therefore as stated " the value is applied to all hits in current and future sessions, until value changes or custom dimension is made inactive." which I assume includes moving from without to with the dimension.